# Activerecord select field from two joined tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my Rails application, I have 3 models **Order** and **Taxi** and **passenger**. Here is the schema of Order table, where **taxi_id** is the foreign key of Taxi, and **passenger_id** is a foregin key of passenger

```
  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "passenger_id"
    t.integer  "taxi_id"
    t.integer  "price"
    .
    .
    .

  end
```

here is Taxi schema:

```
  create_table "taxis", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "taxiNo"
    t.string   "address"
    .
    .

    end
```

and here is my passenger schema

```
    create_table "passengers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "destination"
   end
```

address of passenger clears the origin of passenger, and address of Taxi defines the current address of this taxi.

**I am trying to run this query:**

```
Taxi.joins(:orders => :passenger).select('taxis.id, orders.price, passengers.address, passengers.destination').where(:taxis =>{:id =>29 } ).all
```

As a matter of a fact, I am looking for **price, address and destination of passenger** field only, but the result is `[#<Taxi id: 29, address: "Narva mnt25, Tartu, Estonia">]`.

Here you can find the result:

```
SELECT taxis.id, orders.price, passengers.address, passengers.destination FROM "taxis" INNER JOIN "orders" ON "orders"."taxi_id" = "taxis"."id" INNER JOIN "passengers" ON "passengers"."id" = "orders"."passenger_id" WHERE "taxis"."id" = 29
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Taxi id: 29, address: "Narva mnt25, Tartu, Estonia">]>
```

**It gives me Taxi_address meanwhile i asked for Order.price, Passenger.address and Passenger.destination**

Important point:

I am sure Taxi_id=29 exists

```
Taxi.find_by_id(29)
  Taxi Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "taxis".* FROM "taxis" WHERE "taxis"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 29]]
 => #<Taxi id: 29, taxiNo: "T6", address: "Narva mnt25, Tartu, Estonia", status: "1", avalible_duration: 6, created_at: "2016-01-02 14:44:06", updated_at: "2016-01-02 14:44:06">
```

and I am sure that i have the record in my order table

```
Order.find_by_id(1)

  Order Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 => #<Order id: 1, passenger_id: 40, taxi_id: 29, price: 925, created_at: "2016-01-04 04:40:52", updated_at: "2016-01-04 04:40:52">
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your query is returning this:

```
[#<Taxi id: nil>]
```

...is that you're not selecting the `id` field in your query. You're still getting a record, it just doesn't have an `id`. This would fix it:

```
Taxi.joins(:orders).select('taxis.id, orders.price').where(:taxis =>{:id =>29 } )
```

However, since you want a field from the `orders` table, you should query the Order model, not the Taxi model:

```
Order.select(:id, :price).where(taxi_id: 29)
```

...although if you only care about the values and not the Order or Taxi objects themselves, use `pluck` instead:

```
Order.where(taxi_id: 29).pluck(:price)
# => 925
```

Comment: I query the **Taxi**, because in **Order** i have another foreign key. But to ask a simple question here i just remove it. the exact query is this:
**Taxi.joins(:orders => :passenger).where(:taxis =>{:id =>29 } ).all**

Comment: That is significantly different from the code in your question. Please edit your question to include the actual code you're using. It's not clear why you're using `joins(:orders => :passenger)` if you're not using any fields from `passengers`. Maybe you want [`includes`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) instead?

Comment: i edited my question, could u plz take a look at that